# Find consecutive 0s in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I am working on a homework assignment where I need to find all the 0s connecting to the one on the top, change them to 2s, and return the amount changed.

So far I have:

```
    int[][] cavern = {{1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
                      {1,0,0,1,1,0,1},
                      {1,1,1,0,0,0,1},
                      {1,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                      {1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
                      {0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                      {1,1,1,0,0,0,1}};

    //reads the size of the array
    ...code

    //prints array as a grid (original)
    ...code

    //find zero value in first row
    ...code, sets value to 2


    //change connecting zeros to 2's
    for(int r=0; r<cavern.length; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < cavern[0].length; c++){
        if(cavern[r][c] == 2){
            if((c+1) < cavern[r].length && cavern[r][c+1] == 0){cavern[r][c+1] = 2;}
            else if((c-1) < cavern[r].length && cavern[r][c-1] == 0){cavern[r][c-1] = 2;}
            else if((r+1) < cavern.length && cavern[r+1][c] == 0){cavern[r+1][c] = 2;}
            else if((r-1) < cavern.length && cavern[r-1][c] == 0){cavern[r-1][c] = 2;}
            }   
    }   

    //Print the size of the array
            ...code

    //prints array as a grid with colored values
            ...code
```

with result:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 1 
1 0 0 1 1 2 1 
1 1 1 0 2 2 1 
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

As you can see, the 2s stop after just a few and does not continue to loop through to the end of the zeros.  I feel like I am missing something simple, or made a silly mistake.  I haven't done any programming in years and some basic things are slipping my mind.

I am also having trouble counting all 2's that show up in the array, no matter what I try I either get a value of 1, 2 or it returns an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  With the first answer's suggestions I am now getting this:

```
 1 1 1 1 1 2 1  
 1 0 0 1 1 2 1  
 1 1 1 2 0 2 1   
 1 1 0 2 1 1 1   
 1 2 1 2 1 2 1   
 1 2 1 2 0 2 1   
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0   
 1 1 1 2 2 2 1
```

Comment: Run you code step-by-step under debugger so you can inspect all interim calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numberOfTwos = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < cavern.length; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < cavern[r].length; c++){
        if(cavern[r][c] == 0){
           // We check that we're not on the last row, and also if the next             
           // row is also equals to 0
           if(r < cavern.length-1 && cavern[r+1][c]==0){
              numberOfTwos++;
              // We change both 0's to 2's
              cavern[r][c]=2
              cavern[r+1][c]=2;
           }
           // We also change if we're on a 2 and not on the last column
           else if(c < cavern[0].length-1 && cavern[r][c]==2){
              // if the next one is a 0, we change it for a 2
              if(cavern[r][c+1] ==0){
                 //numberOfTwos++;
                 cavern[r][c+1] =2;
              }
              // if the one under is also a 0, we change it for a 2
              else if(r < cavern.length-1 && cavern[r+1][c] ==0){
                 numberOfTwos++;
                 cavern[r+1][c] =2;
              }
           }
           // We only gonna change the current cavern[r][c] if there's no                                  
           //more rows to check
           else if(r == cavern.length-1){
              numberOfTwos++;
              cavern[r][c]=2;
           }
        }
    } 
}
```

I think this should work. It'll check if the value of every `cavern[r][c]` is equals to zero, then it'll check if the row under is also a zero ( only if there is a row under that's why `r < column.length-1` ) , and if yes, it'll change their values to 2's. Else it'll only change the values of the `cavern[r][c]` since there would be no rows under.

Edit : You can't connect the 0 from top to bottom, it stops 2 line before the last one. I don't know if it's a typo or not.

Comment: This is definitely closer, I am now getting:   
`1 1 1 1 1 2 1  
1 0 0 1 1 2 1  
1 1 1 2 0 2 1   
1 1 0 2 1 1 1   
1 2 1 2 1 2 1   
1 2 1 2 0 2 1   
0 0 0 1 1 1 0   
1 1 1 2 2 2 1 `  

I'll continue to play around with this to see if I can get it to work properly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Monica it's hard to interpret your new results this way lol :)
Can you put those like you previously did ?

Comment: Still returning the same result. Hmm.

Comment: Now it should give your the right answer. In the first loop, in only check your cavern vertically and not horizontally. If you look at the news results, you get the correct 2's from top to bot, but not right to left ( my mistake )

Comment: I am still getting the same result, but it may be something else on my end.  I'll try messing around with the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be something that a recursive solution would be more elegant for.

Have a function called `changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners()` which simply does the job for a single cell, *plus* all valid partner cells. In pseudo-code, that would be along the lines of:

```python
def changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, ypos):
    # No action if we have moved outside the array.

    if xpos < 0 or xpos >= xwidth or ypos < 0 or ypos >= yheight:
        return

    # No action if cell is not a zero.

    if array[xpos,ypos] != 0:
        return

    # Change it then do all partners of that cell (right, left, down, up).

    array[xpos,ypos] = 2

    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos+1, ypos)
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos-1, ypos)
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, ypos+1)
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, ypos-1)
```

The checks up front prevent you from moving outside of the array and processing any non-zero cells.

The immediate setting of the cell to two, in conjunction with that check above that filters out non-zero cells, will prevent infinite regress since moving back to a cell that you've already processed will be filtered as not being zero any more (it will now be a two).

Then, to use this function, you just need to call it for each cell in the first row:

```
for xpos in 0 to xwidth-1 inclusive:
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, 0)
```

In terms of a proof-of-concept, here's some Python code that does what you need:

```
def changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, ypos):
    if xpos < 0 or xpos >= xwidth or ypos < 0 or ypos >= yheight:
        return
    if array[ypos][xpos] != 0:
        return

    array[ypos][xpos] = 2

    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos+1, ypos)
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos-1, ypos)
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, ypos+1)
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(array, xwidth, yheight, xpos, ypos-1)

cavern = [[1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
          [1,0,0,1,1,0,1],
          [1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
          [1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
          [1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
          [1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
          [0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
          [1,1,1,0,0,0,1]]

for line in cavern:
    print(line)

for xpos in range(len(cavern[0])):
    changeZeroToTwoPlusPartners(cavern, len(cavern[0]), len(cavern), xpos, 0)

print("-----")
for line in cavern:
    print(line)
```

The output is (and you'll see the transformation is correct if you do it manually, changing every `0` on the top line to a `2` then recursively changing any `0` adjacent to a `2` into yet another `2`):

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
-----
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def BitmapHoles(strArr):
    ans = 0
    n = len(strArr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(len(strArr[i])):
            if strArr[i][j] == 0:
                if i < n-1 and strArr[i+1][j] == 0:
                    ans +=1
                    strArr[i][j] = 2
                    strArr[i+1][j] = 2
                elif j < len(strArr[0])-1 and strArr[i][j] == 2:
                    if strArr[i][j+1] == 0:
                        strArr[i][j+1] = 2
                    elif i < n-1 and strArr[i+1][j] == 0:
                        ans += 1
                        strArr[i+1][j] = 2
                elif i == n-1:
                    ans += 1
                    strArr[i][j] = 2

    return ans


print(BitmapHoles([[0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0]]))

print(BitmapHoles([[1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
                      [1,0,0,1,1,0,1],
                      [1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
                      [1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
                      [1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                      [1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
                      [0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
                      [1,1,1,0,0,0,1]]))
```